# How to check whether a virtual object is colliding with another?

Tags: ros, planning-environment, collision-object, planning-scene, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have to simulate a planning environment where objects whose poses are randomly determined are added.

It is obvious to check if the just-added object is in collision with the robot, as in [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Adding%20Virtual%20Objects%20to%20the%20Planning%20Scene).

How to check if it is in collision with the other existing objects?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43837/how-to-check-whether-a-virtual-object-is-colliding-with-another?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need this method:

```
bool isObjectInCollision(const std::string& object_name);
```

it's a public method of planning_environment::CollisionModels.

besides, if you want to know exactly which objects are in collision with the target object, use this method:

```
void getAllEnvironmentCollisionsForObject(const std::string& object_name, 
                        std::vector<arm_navigation_msgs::ContactInformation>& contacts,
                        unsigned int num_per_pair = 1);
```

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-11-05**:
Please note that the goal is to check whether an object is in collision with another object, *not* with a robot. AFAIK, your answer works for the latter. Anyway, thanks.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-05**:
i don't agree with you. getAllEnvironmentCollisionsForObject() will return all the collisions for the specified object, no matter it is a robot link, or another object. you can check the src of this method.

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-11-08**:
Well, to call isObjectInCollision(), we need an instance of CollisionModel whose constructor needs a robot description. Therefore, even if we have the object cm from rbt_desc, cm.isObjectInCollision("obj") will tell whether "obj" is in collision with the rbt_desc's robot. CMIIW.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-09**:
well, i have not test the function isObjectInCollision(), but i do test the function getAllEnvironmentCollisionsForObject() and it does work. and of course, you need an instance of CollisionModel.